# VBA MS Office Word Excel Cyrillic characters problem

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, cyrillic, msgbox

I am VBA advanced user.
I have many PC's, Laptop's and all of them have Windows and MS Office 2013 or 2016 installed
The described below problem is only on my Dell Laptop.
OS is Windows 10 Pro, Office is 2016 Professional Plus.
I have this problem: My Cyrillic chars only on 1 from 6 PC's are not OK.
ÊÈÐÈËÈÖÀ КИРИЛИЦА OR ????????
By example:
When I am in VBA coding mode and try to enter FORM Caption КИРИЛИЦА in Properties Window - result is ???????? - on Form Title bar and in Properties Window Caption Value
When I enter Command Button Caption value in Properties Window КИРИЛИЦА result in Properties Window and on Command button caption is ????????

But when I enter Command button caption direct on Command button - result on Command button is КИРИЛИЦА, In Properties Window is ???????? again.

I try change user form caption programmatically:
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Me.Caption = "КИРИЛИЦА"
End Sub

Result is ÊÈÐÈËÈÖÀ

I try all known methods - direct windows fonts editing via registry, Winaero Tweaker fonts editing.....

But on this Dell G5 Cyrillic is a problem. Only in Office 2016 VBA, msgbox command, VBA Properties window, Object captions.

Please, help!

Answer (score 1):

Try to set up russian language for non-unicode programs (see the Control panel's regional settings):

[image: language for non-unicode programs]